# Gaussian integrals with cumulative normals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, normal-distribution, error-function, gaussian-integral

**Definitions:**

Let 
$$\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2} $$
be the standard normal probability density function (pdf) and
$$
\Phi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \phi(t) dt = \frac{1}{2}\left[ 1 + \text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \right]
$$
be its cumulative distribution function (cdf).

---

**Problem:**

For a side project I am dealing with, as an intermediate step of an algorithm I need to solve definite integrals of the following form:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^p \phi\left(x\right) \Phi(a + b x) dx
$$

for $p = 0,1,2$.

For $p = 0$ and $p = 1$, the solutions are listed on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions). They are:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi\left(x\right) \Phi(a + b x) dx = \Phi\left(\frac{a}{t} \right)
$$
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \phi\left(x\right) \Phi(a + b x) dx = \frac{b}{t} \phi\left(\frac{a}{t} \right)
$$
with $t = \sqrt{1 + b^2}$.

---

**Questions:**

- What is the solution for $p = 2$?
- More in general, what is the simplest approach to solve these integrals?

Comment: http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn1p1_A1b.pdf 4.3.7

Comment: @tired Holy wow!  Why did you not tell me of this soon!?

Comment: @Simply beautiful sorry, just forgot it ;)

Comment: To derive identities from wikipedia for $p=0$ differentiate w.r.t. to $a$, for $p=1$ combine this with an integration by parts. $p=2$ should be solvable by similar methods

Comment: @tired: Thanks for the reference. However, Eq. 4.3.7 seems to apply only for no shift (i.e. $a = 0$ in my notation).

Comment: @lacerbi i know, i intended this as a reference to crosscheck the related generalizations

Comment: @tired Ah dang... I was close...maybe I'll redo my answer later.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt that'd be great! :D

Comment: Let us investigate the integral

>$$
I(a,b)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)\Phi(a+bx)
$$

now let's denote $'$ the derivative w.r.t $a$. Applying this operation to the above integrals yields, after rescaling ($t=\sqrt{1+b^2}$)

$$
I^{'}(a,b)=\frac{1}{\pi t}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(y^2+2\frac{ab}{t}y+a^2)\right)\right)
$$

.....

Comment: ....completing the square gives

$$
I^{'}(a,b)=\frac{1}{\pi t}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(a^2-\frac{a^2 b^2}{t^2})}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi} t}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(a^2-\frac{a^2 b^2}{t^2})}
$$

integrating back w.r.t $a$ gives

$$
I(a,b)=\frac{1}{2}\text{erf}\left(\frac a{\sqrt2t}\right)+C
$$

since $\phi(x)$ is normalized and $I(a,0)=\Phi(a)$ we can fix the constant of integration to be $\frac12$ and we get

>$$
I(a,b)=\Phi\left(\frac at\right)
$$

The generalisations you are mentioning follow the same line of reasoning, so i leave them to you!

Comment: For $p=1$ essentially the only additional information you need is that the interval  of an odd function over an even region equals zero

Comment: @tired: Thanks for the hint. Yes, the basic trick is to derive under the integral, from there it's just a matter of manipulation and matching terms. I was able to re-derive independently the results for $p=0$ and $p=1$, I'll work next on the $p=2$ case.